# How to tell TypeScript that an object may only return object properties from values in an array?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to have the return object from a function recognized by TypeScript as only allowing keys which are string values based on array in the argument passed to the function. The return may would be a subset of keys from a master list of strings which are valid for the input array. I'm not clear how to reference the actual values provided to myArr.

```
declare type ListOfStrings = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'car';
function doSomething(myArr: ListOfStrings[]) {
    // const returnObj: { [key: ListOfStrings]: number } = {}; // Invalid: index signature parameter type cannot be a union type
    // const returnObj: { [key: string]: number } = {}; // Valid, but not specific enough to catch the mistake below
    const returnObj: { [Properties in ListOfStrings]?: number } = {}; // More specific, but still not specificly based on the actual values of myArr enough to catch the mistake below
    for (const entry of myArr) returnObj[entry] = Math.random();
    return returnObj;
}

const finalObj = doSomething(['banana', 'car']);
console.log(finalObj.apple); // FAILS TO CATCH MY ERROR: no TS lint error here because the basic string check passes
```

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: This is not something the compiler will help. The compiler only deals with **values known at compile time**, not values passed as parameters or anything that is only know at runtime.

Comment: @Alejandro it's actually achievable if the union like `ListOfStrings` is given. You only need to type it [strong enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727395/6532549).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function generic

```
function doSomething<T extends ListOfStrings>(myArr:T[] ) {
    const returnObj: { [Properties in T]?: number } = {}; 
    for (const entry of myArr) returnObj[entry] = Math.random();
    return returnObj;
}
```

This way the final object will have the right shape

```
const finalObj = doSomething(['banana', 'car']);
const finalObj: {
   banana?: number | undefined;
   car?: number | undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and combine it with [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```
type ListOfStrings = 'apple' | 'banana' | 'car';

function doSomething<
    T extends ListOfStrings,             // Force the `arr` items to be one of this union.
    K extends Extract<ListOfStrings, T>  // Extract only the included values in the `arr`.
>(arr: T[]){
    const ret = {} as { [k in K]: number }; // Map union `K` to the props of return value.

    for (const entry of arr){
        ret[entry as K] = Math.random();    // Tell the compiler the value of `arr` is one of K.
    }

    return ret;
}

const ok = doSomething(['banana', 'car']);  // ok
ok.banana; // ok
ok.orange; // error

const err = doSomething(['banana', 'orange']);  // error
```

[Demo in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AeQGYGVgCc4DsDmCUAvFAOQCGYYANhGVAD7kBGFu7FDzZAxhVjIBuALAAocagCuuXsDgB7XFAAmC9AoC2EYAAs8+ADziopqABUoEAB7AIuFUXhI0mHAQQAaMz99QA9P5QAGIKWLzQetAABgJY0VBwdppEwApQLNBKWahQeohQMoq4AHQmZgDSVrb2jlAAorZYFHKGzigY2AZeFgB8poENTS3AUEo0IHm60Hi8NFIqECpQAG4U8xBEeFMxcdFlYr0AFHEAXBYA2gC6AJQA3uWmvEpIUFg6JFB3AL5QFER3KAXADWiWUFSu51wUk0mSwUG+QgCQQAslRCrhilBohUEmkdlAwFgFGAiApcu9gFIsMo1hsDo8oKgwlAjs9cK97NhJuS-lgsPdGT5KRcuVhJv8oBDPmi9CVmg4tEcbkizINzBAaDQCc9NGA4HR4VFVuspDlsXtEmTcOaKgcfN9xIzKdTlJTRGJHRIxOzXgpQaQ1BptPkCEcLmQ2BwOGRvHwBGRbqrBv7xP6SlHOEiU8C08CSmF2PgINmghB+WEnT6XqNy-DA+otDp9GGI5mY3HCwR6EmBmWK1ggA).

Answer (score 0):

not perfect but should work

```typescript
function doSomething<Keys extends string>(keys: Keys[]): Partial<Record<Keys, number>> {
    const returnObj: Partial<Record<Keys, number>> = {};
    for (const entry of keys) {
        returnObj[entry] = Math.random();
    }
    return returnObj
}

const x = doSomething(['a', 'b']);
x.c // err
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkvY0m)